# Can node-soap handle multiple schemas with different namespaces in a single WSDL?

Tags: xml, node.js, soap, wsdl, node-soap

I am using [node-soap](https://github.com/vpulim/node-soap) to interface with an existing SOAP API. I'm running into a problem with multiple schemas and namespaces that, from what I'm reading, may be a known issue. Here's the setup, I'm interfacing with one WSDL file with two schemas:

WSDL (attributes and elements removed for brevity):

```
<wsdl:definitions xmlns:tns="[rm-nsurl]" targetNamespace="[rm-nsurl]" ...>

   <!-- schema1 -->
  <schema xmlns:tns="[cm-nsurl]" targetNamespace="[cm-nsurl]" ...>
    <complexType abstract="true" name="Operation">
      <sequence>
        <element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="operator" type="tns:Operator">...</element>
      </sequence>
    </<complexType
  </schema>

   <!-- schema2 -->
  <schema xmlns:cm="[cm-nsurl]" xmlns:tns="[rm-nsurl]" targetNamespace="[rm-nsurl]" ...>
    <complexType name="UserListOperation">
      <complexContent>
        <extension base="cm:Operation">...</extension>
      </complexContent>
    </complexType>
  </schema>

  ...
</wsdl:definitions>
```

The important detail is that the two schemas define `tns` as different values. When a type in schema2 references an element in schema1 (`cm:Operation`), it uses the explicit namespace of cm (good so far), but then jumping into that referenced type in schema1 we are now seeing the `tns` namespace used and in schema1 `tns` is `cm`. This causes a problem because node-soap is using a single overall value for `tns` which in this case happens to be `rm` and it does not explicitly use the `cm` namespace when required.

Here's an example where I'm seeing the problem:

Request object passed to the WSDL method:

```
{
  operations: [{
    operator: 'SET',
    operand: {
      id: 'abcd1234',
      description: 'a description'
    }
  }]
};
```

Node-soap generated request XML:

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:tns="[rm-nsurl]" xmlns:cm="[cm-nsurl]" ...>

  <soap:Body>
    <mutate xmlns="[rm-nsurl]">
      <operations>
        <operator>SET</operator>
        <operand><id>abcd1234</id><description>a description</description></operand>
      </operations>
    </mutate>
  </soap:Body>

</soap:Envelope>
```

The request errors with

```
[OperatorError.OPERATOR_NOT_SUPPORTED @ operations[0], RequiredError.REQUIRED @ operations[0].operator]
```

I'm able to get around the problem by manually including the cm namespace for the `operator` element in the request object [as mentioned in the readme](https://github.com/vpulim/node-soap#overriding-the-namespace-prefix). I'm wondering if there is a better way to use node-soap in this situation, since all of the required information is specified in the WSDL, or have I run into one of the kinks that node-soap has regarding namespaces?

Here's the same request object with the workaround:

```
{
  operations: [{
    'cm:operator': 'SET',
    operand: {
      id: 'abcd1234',
      description: 'a description'
    }
  }]
};
```

Concrete details: [This is the WSDL I'm using](https://adwords.google.com/api/adwords/rm/v201509/AdwordsUserListService?wsdl). I am running into this problem using a `mutate` operation and it is the `operator` element that is getting namespaced incorrectly.